# Posting data to server with jQuery

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

So I have a basic cordova app created. I added jquery and am trying to make a request to a url.
The target is to post data, but I'm testing with a GET method. 
The problem is that the response is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)", but when I open the url from a browser, the response is displayed.

I've been at this for a day and a half, I've gone through alot topics on the internet and tried different things, but couldn't get the job done. If you have any ideas it would be great!

My goal is to create an android app, in which you fill several fields with text, save them on the device, and when connected to wifi tap a button to push the data in the file to a server. So if you have any suggestions on what other I can use instead of cordova, I`d appreciate it.

EDIT - here is the code:
So as I said, plain app created with cordova.
This is the index.html and the default index.js at which end I added the ajax:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'url',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  },
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(req, err) {
    console.log(req);
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="app">
    <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
    <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
      <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
      <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you share your code and more details?

Comment: what you have tried yet?

Comment: I've included the code I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provide a way to connect Server.(i.e)HTTP asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.All jQuery AJAX methods use the ajax() method. This method is mostly used for requests where the other methods cannot be used.

This is the simple method to connect your server.

$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});

use this method.No need to add headers in the client side. please add it in the back end to support cross platform issues(CORS).

[To know more please refer ][1]

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/